# Steam reports I'm missing libc.so.6 even though I have them installed

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg, steam

Steam reports `You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6` even though I can find them under `/lib/i386-linux-gnu` and `/usr/lib/libc.so.6`. For some reason, this started happening after I installed the nvidia-460 drivers. I suspect it might be a linking problem, but here's the output when I run `find / -name libc.so.6`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/libc.so.6
/home/alyssonfd/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_soldier/var/deploy-0.20210309.0/files/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/home/alyssonfd/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime_soldier/var/deploy-0.20210309.0/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/home/alyssonfd/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime/scout_0.20200505.0/files/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/home/alyssonfd/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/SteamLinuxRuntime/scout_0.20200505.0/files/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: To be completely sure please reinstall relevant packages by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6:i386 steam:i386` .

Comment: How did you install steam, because your paths are quite different than the ones I have.  There is a steam-installer package, try that if you reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue on my Ubuntu 20.04. I've tried many advices like add remove/reinstall/add-arcitecture etc. But that has no take any effect. You shuold be sure that the libc6 already installed on you pc and the i386 architecture also added. But in my case the problem was solved with just one following command from [this solution](https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/3051737278926328407/?ctp=3#c3390672107126939839)

```
**$ ./steam.sh --reset**

steam.sh[181403]: Installing bootstrap /home/user/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
steam.sh[181403]: Reset complete!
```

Steam was started without any errors after it.
I'll be happy if this will be helpful to you